# Singular del Pezzo surfaces and degeneration of root systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-surfaces, root-systems

Let $S$ be a smooth del Pezzo surface of degree $d$ and $K_S^*$ the anticanonical class. It is well known that the set of classes

$$R(S)=\{\alpha\in H^2(S,\mathbb Z)|\alpha^2=-2,\alpha\cdot K_S^*=0\},$$

together with intersection pairing is isomorphic to a root system $R_d$ of rank $9-d$, where $R_d$ from $d=1$ to $6$ is $E_8,E_7,E_6,D_5,A_4,A_2\times A_1$. Moreover, Each root can be written as $[L_1]-[L_2]$, where $L_1,L_2$ are two disjoint lines on $S$.

I'm particularly interested in the $d=3$ case, where $S$ is a cubic surface, and the corresponding root system $E_6$ has 72 roots. I'd like to know

**Question 1:** Is there a notion of the root system on singular del Pezzo surfaces? Is there any related reference?

Now let $S$ be a normal del Pezzo surface of degree $d$ with at worst ADE singularities. Then there is a minimal resolution $\pi:S'\to S$, where $S'$ is a weak del Pezzo surface, which arises blowing up $9-d$ bubble points on $\mathbb P^2$. Moreover, $\pi$ is given by anticanonical map $|K_{S'}|$ and contracts all effective $(-2)$ curves. Since $S'$ is deformation equivalent to a smooth del Pezzo surface, the root system of $S'$ is also isomorphic to $R_d$. According to [Dolgachev's book](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Eeizadi/207A-14/Dolgachev-topics.pdf), section 8.4 and 9.2.3, and also see [Martin Bright's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/339010), the set of effective $(-2)$ curves on $S'$ correspond to a sub root system $R_e\subseteq R_d$. Such sub-root systems are classified. Moreover, the rank $r=\text{rank}(R_e)$ coincides with the number of the $(-2)$-effective curves.

To me, the roots on singular $S$ should be a degeneration of the root system $R_d$. It should be certain "complement" of the sub-root system $R_e$ of the $(-2)$ curves occur in the resolution. However, the orthogonal complement does not seems to the correct notion, since strict transform of a line through the singular point will have nontrivial intersection with the exceptional curves, and there should be "roots" as differences of lines through the singularity.

The notion of root system $R(S)$ on singular $S$ that I have in mind is a quotient:

**Definition 1:** Let $R(S)$ be the quotient set $R_d/R_e:=R_d/\sim$, where the equivalence relation on $R_d$ is $r_1\sim r_2$ iff $r_1-r_2\in R_e$.

Such a quotient is just a set and does not have a root system structure in general. (Although the quotient seems to behave well for type $A$ root systems, so for $d\ge 5$ cases, the quotients correspond to the Dynkin diagram by removing the sub-Dynkin diagram corresponding to $R_e$).

For example, for a cubic surface with an $A_1$ singularity, $R(S)=E_6/A_1$ has 50 "roots"; for a quartic del Pezzo surface with an $A_1$ singularity, $R(S)=D_5/A_1$ has 26 "roots". As far as I know, 50 and 26 are not the number of roots of any root systems (even reducible).

The reason for me to consider this quotient is that the class group $\text{Cl}(S)$ arises as a surjection $\text{Pic}(S')\twoheadrightarrow \text{Cl}(S)$ with kernel generated by the set of effective $(-2)$ curves. However, I haven't seen any reference ever discussed such quotient.

**Question 2**: Is there a Lie theory interpretation of the quotient in Definition 1?

Any suggestions and comments are welcome!

Comment: There is an excellent book precisely devoted to this subject: *Séminaire sur les singularités des surfaces*, LN 777, Springer.

Comment: @abx Thank you, I roughly went through that book before, it discussed the relation of the sub root system determined by the singularity, but it didn't seem to discuss the quotient or the "root system" on the singular del Pezzo surface.